# Steady-state of an expectation value of an oscillator system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, oscillators

For context, I am dealing with [an equation of motion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7044) for the expectation value $\beta=\left\langle\hat{b}\right\rangle$ of a quantum van der Pol oscillator. But I would love a more general explanation.

Given an equation of motion for the expectation value $a$ of some (not necessarily Hermitian) operator $\hat{A}$,
$$
\frac{da}{dt}=f(t,a)
$$
**does $da/dt=0$ imply the steady state of the dynamics of the corresponding system?**

---

My analysis so far tells me that this is not true. For example, if $\hat{A}$ is hermitian then $a$ corresponds to some observable. And an observable is not necessarily stationary for the system to be steady. This is reflected in oscillatory systems where the steady state of, say, position still changes with time. If this were true, then **how are we supposed to relate the steady state of the system with the evolution of the expectation value?**

Comment: If you forget  about expectation values and the underlying quantum dynamics, how would you identify the steady state of a classical system starting from it's equations of motion?

Comment: When a linear "RLC" circuit is driven by a *causal* otherwise arbitrary periodic excitation then after a turn-on exponentially decaying transient the output, any branch current or node voltage will have the same periodicity as that of the excitation; this is steady state for a linear system. A classical van der Pol oscillator tracks a single sinusoid excitation asymptotically to a limit cycle, its steady state, with the same periodicity. Is the same even true for an *arbitrary* periodic or multi-periodic excitation?